# Creating a normalized histogram of log intensities with GEO datasets

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I'm trying to create a density/log intensity histogram of a normalized GEO microarray dataset. I have tried doing this several different ways, but unfortunately I have had little to no luck.

What is the best (easiest?) approach to creating a histogram after the dataset has been "normalized"?

I am currently following these codes as an example:

```
# download the BioC installation routines
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
# install the core packages
biocLite()
# install the GEO libraries
biocLite("GEOquery")
library(GEOquery)
getGEOSuppFiles("GSE20986")
untar("GSE20986/GSE20986_RAW.tar", exdir="data")
cels <- list.files("data/", pattern = "[gz]")
sapply(paste("data", cels, sep="/"), gunzip)
cels
library(simpleaffy)
celfiles<-read.affy(covdesc="phenodata.txt", path="data")
celfiles
celfiles.gcrma<-gcrma(celfiles)
celfiles.gcrma
```

However, when I get to the gcrma(celfiles) line, I end up with the following warning:

```
Computing affinities.
Error in matrix(NA, nrow = max(cbind(pmIndex, mmIndex)), ncol = 1) : 
  invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)
```

Comment: Could you post the complete error/warning? Beside what do you do with the output of `sapply`? Also do you know that you don't need to install the libraries each time you want to run these analysis?

Comment: This is an old post, but I was able to use the Plot.AffyBatch function to create a normalized plot of the log intensities.

Comment: @statsguyz Please consider sharing your solution as an answer.